# How to save plots that have been generated using plotly in file formats TIFF ot EPS

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I want to save a number of plots that I generate in R-studio using `plotly`. I want to save them as high quality images: either as TIFF or EPS.

I am trying the following code for the tiff ones:

```
tiff(file="plot.tiff",
     width=6, height=4, units="in", res=100)
fig<-plot_ly(OUT, x = ~x, color = ~y) %>%
  add_histogram()
dev.off()
```

This is the code I am trying for the eps ones:

```
setEPS()
postscript("plot.eps")
fig<-plot_ly(OUT, x = ~x, color = ~y) %>%
      add_histogram()
dev.off()
```

In both cases files are blank.

P.S. Plots are displayed correctly in the Rstudio viewer.

Comment: Could you please share sampledata, such that the plotly-call is valid call?

Comment: See https://plotly.com/r/static-image-export/